# Launching a registered mime helper application

Tags: windows, delphi, mime, mime-types

I used to be able to launch a locally installed helper application by registering a given mime-type in the Windows registry. This enabled me to allow users to be able to click once on a link to the current install of our internal browser application. This worked fine in Internet Explorer 5 (most of the time) and Firefox but now does not work in Internet Explorer 7.

The filename passed to my shell/open/command is not the full physical path to the downloaded install package. The path parameter I am handed by IE is

```
"C:\Document and Settings\chq-tomc\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\
  EIPortal_DEV_2_0_5_4[1].expd"
```

This unfortunately does not resolve to the physical file when calling `FileExists()` or when attempting to create a `TFileStream` object.

The physical path is missing the Internet Explorer hidden caching sub-directory for Temporary Internet Files of `"Content.IE5\ALBKHO3Q"` whose absolute path would be expressed as

```
"C:\Document and Settings\chq-tomc\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\ 
  Content.IE5\ALBKHO3Q\EIPortal_DEV_2_0_5_4[1].expd"
```

Yes, the sub-directories are randomly generated by IE and that should not be a concern so long as IE passes the full path to my helper application, which it unfortunately is not doing.

Installation of the mime helper application is not a concern. It is installed/updated by a global login script for all 10,000+ users worldwide. The mime helper is only invoked when the user clicks on an internal web page with a link to an installation of our Desktop browser application. That install is served back with a mime-type of `"application/x-expeditors"`. The registration of the `".expd"` / `"application/x-expeditors"` mime-type looks like this.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.expd] 
@="ExpeditorsInstaller"
"Content Type"="application/x-expeditors"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ExpeditorsInstaller]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,01,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ExpeditorsInstaller\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ExpeditorsInstaller\shell\open]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ExpeditorsInstaller\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\projects\\desktop2\\WebInstaller\\WebInstaller.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/x-expeditors]
"Extension"=".expd"
```

I had considered enumerating all of a user's IE cache entries but I would be concerned with how long it may take to examine them all or that I may end up finding an older cache entry before the current entry I am looking for. However, the bracketed filename suffix `"[n]"` may be the unique key.

I have tried wininet method `GetUrlCacheEntryInfo` but that requires the URL, not the virtual path handed over by IE.

My hope is that there is a Shell function that given a virtual path will hand back the physical path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some follow-up to close out this question.

Turned out the real issue was how I was creating the file handle using TFileStream. I changed to open with **fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite** which solved what turned out to be a file locking issue.

```
srcFile := TFileStream.Create(physicalFilename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sub-directories created by IE are randomly generated, so you won't be able guarantee that it will be named the same every time, and the problem I see with the registry method is that it only works when the file is still in the cache...emptying the cache would purge the file requiring yet another installation.

Would it not be better to install this helper into application data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but perhaps this may lead you in the right direction: try using URL cache functions from the wininet DLL: [FindFirstUrlCacheEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384026(VS.85).aspx), [FindNextUrlCacheEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384049(VS.85).aspx), [FindCloseUrlCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384015(VS.85).aspx) for enumeration and when you locate an entry whose local file name matches the given path maybe you can use [RetrieveUrlCacheEntryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385365(VS.85).aspx) to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar system with the X-Appl browser to display WAML web applications and it works perfectly. Maybe you should have a look at how they managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iexplore is passing the shell namespace "name" of the file rather than the filesystem name.

I dont think there is a documented way to be passed a shell item id on the command line - explorer does it to itself, but there are marshaling considerations as shell item ids are (pointers to) binary data structures that are only valid in a single process.

What I might try doing is:
1. Call SHGetDesktopFolder which will return the root IShellFolder object of the shell namespace.
2. Call the IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName to turn the name you are given back into a shell item id list.
3. Try the IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOF with the SHGDN_FORPARSING flag - which, frankly, feels like w'eve just gone in a complete circle and are back where we started. Because I think its this API thats ultimately responsible for returning the "wrong" filesystem relative path.